# Not able to draw image onto JButton using ImageIcons

Tags: java, jbutton, imageicon

I am trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game which is in progress. I have problems loading images onto JButton. I have just programmed a single button right now. I have made a res file which is like res/image/Cross.png and Circle.png . They are in the build path. But even after clicking the button, image is not displayed
My one and only class

```
    package com.arjav.tictactoe ;

    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    public class TTT implements ActionListener{
    JFrame frame ;

    int turn = 0 ;
    ImageIcon cross = new ImageIcon("Cross.png");
    ImageIcon circle = new ImageIcon("Circle.png");

    public JButton x1y1 = new JButton("Click me");
    public JButton x2y1 = new JButton("Click me");
    public JButton x3y1 = new JButton("Click me");
    public JButton x1y2 = new JButton("Click me");
    public JButton x2y2 = new JButton("Click me");
    public JButton x3y2 = new JButton("Click me");
    public JButton x1y3 = new JButton("Click me");
    public JButton x2y3 = new JButton("Click me");
    public JButton x3y3 = new JButton("Click me");

    public TTT(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Let's Play Tic Tac Toe ?? YES!!");
        frame.setSize(300 , 300);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        init();
    }
    public void init(){
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(3 , 3);
        frame.setLayout(layout);
        frame.add(x1y1);
        frame.add(x2y1);
        frame.add(x3y1);
        frame.add(x1y2);
        frame.add(x2y2);
        frame.add(x3y2);
        frame.add(x1y3);
        frame.add(x2y3);
        frame.add(x3y3);
        x1y1.addActionListener(this);
        x2y1.addActionListener(this);
        x3y1.addActionListener(this);
        x1y2.addActionListener(this);
        x2y2.addActionListener(this);
        x3y2.addActionListener(this);
        x1y3.addActionListener(this);
        x2y3.addActionListener(this);
        x3y3.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == x1y1){

            if(turn == 0) {x1y1.setIcon(circle);
            turn++ ;
            System.out.println(turn);
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       TTT main = new TTT();
    }
}
```

Comment: It even prints 1 in the console

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`ImageIcon circle = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Circle.png"));` 
instead of 
`ImageIcon circle = new ImageIcon("Circle.png");`. If your icon image is not inside of default package than you have to use path to icon like `"/res/image/Circle.png"`